# Avoiding lock errors on new writes while deleting records on InnoDB table

Tags: java, mysql

I have an (java) application that runs database purge queries on startup. Depending on the user, these queries could wind up removing hundreds of thousands of records. I've broken up the queries so that they're limited to 5000 records, with some breathing room between each query running.

The table uses InnoDB.

An example query:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE epoch <= '1388094517' LIMIT 5000;
```

However, certain users are seeing various errors with lock problems:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Advising mysql config changes are pretty much not possible because this is a distributed application. What steps can I take to make sure the delete queries are not causing locking errors?

The application begins logging data on startup and needs to be able to write to the database while the current delete query is running.

Comment: What happens, when you systematically decrease limit to, say, 1000, 500, 100? Are there reliable statistics regarding dependency of error-frequency from limit? What happens, if you insert 10 msec, 100 msec, 500 msec delay (Thread.sleep) between deletes?

Comment: I can't tell because these errors mainly happen for some of our users who usually aren't terribly capable of helping to diagnose the issue. I personally have never had this issue so I suspect it's an issue on slower/older machines. I just want to do all I can to make sure purges can run smoothly. If there's nothing I can do, I'll just make an FAQ with helpful links increasing lock waits, buffer size, etc.

Comment: Not really a solution, but a little trick you might try: insert delay between "delete" queries to give other queries some room. I did not try it, so the result is not guaranteed. Also, this Q&A might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373843/meet-deadlock-when-deleting-different-records-from-same-table-in-different-trans?rq=1

Comment: We usually do - by default, delete queries are delayed by 1 second, though maybe older systems could use a longer delay.

Comment: Was this the table you were asking about in your [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725170)?  InnoDB will lock every row it scans if the `WHERE` clause can't be resolved with an index... you *absolutely need* that index.